# Maxmind GeoIP Not Working

Tags: .htaccess, geolocation, geoip

I have been trying to get GeoIP country redirect to work. But it seems to break the site everytime I edit my .htaccess file.

(FYI I'm using cloud hosting; Not sure if there's any difference in procedures from normal share hosting)

Here is my code:

```
# MaxMind GeoIP Redirecting 
GeoIPEnable On
GeoIPDBFile /applications/waterlinecooling/public_html/GeoIP/GeoIP.dat

# Start Redirecting countries

# Thailand
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{ENV:GEOIP_COUNTRY_CODE} ^TH$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.waterlinecooling.com/$1 [L]

# Vietnam
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{ENV:GEOIP_COUNTRY_CODE} ^VN$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.waterlinecooling.com/home-vi_vi/$1 [L]

# Indonesia
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{ENV:GEOIP_COUNTRY_CODE} ^ID$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.waterlinecooling.com/home-id_id/$1 [L]

# The Rest Of The World
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{ENV:GEOIP_COUNTRY_CODE} ^A1$
RewriteCond %{ENV:GEOIP_COUNTRY_CODE} ^A2$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.waterlinecooling.com/home-th_en/$1 [L]
```

Comment: As far as i see, there isn't nothing wrong, check this but dunno..
https://dev.maxmind.com/geoip/legacy/mod_geoip2/

Comment: I was referring to that documentation as well. Any other way to do redirects?